# Highlight selected text everywhere?

Tags: front-end, style, syntax-highlighting

Notebook++ has a very useful feature which highlights all occurrences of certain text once it has been selected with the mouse cursor in one spot:

[image]

It is very useful in order to jump between different spots with the same function name quickly. Does Mathematica have the same feature? If so, how to activate it?